# Virtualbox - folder does not automatically mount, Windows 7 host Ubuntu 17.10 guest

Tags: network-shares, virtualbox

I'm trying to use Virtualbox's shared folder functionality, and I can't get the automount folder feature to work.

I've followed directions in various SO/AskUbuntu questions, and it seems like I set up shared folders correctly.

More details:

Mounting the folder with `sudo mount -t vboxsf vbox_shared /media/vbox_shared` works, including write access.

I've installed Virtualbox Guest Additions, and `lsmod | grep vboxguest` returns `vboxguest    294912  2 vboxsf,vboxvideo`.

I've run `sudo usermod -G vboxsf -a <username>` to add myself to the group.

I've restarted the virtual machine.

In Virtualbox settings, I've set Folder Path: `C:\Users\<myusername>\vbox_shared`, Folder Name: `vbox_shared`, Auto-mount and Make Permanent are checked.

Host is Windows 7 Enterprise, Guest is Ubuntu Server 17.10, Virtualbox 5.2.6.

What else could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 4):

Automount performed by appropriate systemd unit service:

- **virtualbox-guest-utils.service** - if you have installed virtualbox-guest-dkms and virtualbox-guest-utils

or

- **vboxadd-service.service** - if you have installed VBoxLinuxAdditions.run from VirtualBox virtual CD.

In the both of the cases appropriate service possible failure to start caused by unit dependecies.

Possible solution:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full vboxadd-service
```

or

```
sudo systemctl edit --full virtualbox-guest-utils
```

and remove "systemd-timesync.service" from "Conflicts=" line in [Unit] section. Then reboot.

**UPDATED**
If you'll update Virtual Guest Additions you'll possible have to change manually version number in the `vboxadd-service`. See also [selectstriker2 comment below](https://superuser.com/questions/1295025/virtualbox-folder-does-not-automatically-mount-windows-7-host-ubuntu-17-10-gu/1349958?noredirect=1#comment2083435_1349958).

Comment: So I ran into an issue when updating from 5.2.18 to 5.2.22 which caused the vboxadd-service configuration to not update from .18 to .22. This caused vboxadd-service to fail to start. I fixed those lines in the file using this method and was able to get the vboxadd-service to actually start

Comment: Changing the version number worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Updating the version from 6.1.26 to 7.0.10 (the new extension pack) worked for me.