# After upgrade to Ubuntu LTS-18, VirtualBox shared folders marked "auto-mount" don't mount anymore

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Running VirtualBox latest (5.2.18) without incident until I updated to Ubuntu LTS-18.  (Host is OS/X.)  Now, shared folders marked "auto-mount" do not mount.  (I reinstalled "Guest Additions" from the extension-pack at "virtualbox.org" and restarted, just in case. but no effect.)

I do see the `/media/sf_sharename` folder for all of the specified shares, but there's nothing in them:  they're not mounted!

I *can* use `sudo mount` explicitly, and when I do so the content of the shared folder now appears.  But, when I specify "auto mount" in the VirtualBox shared-folders setting, I should not have to do this.

Notice that I didn't change anything at all about VirtualBox:  I *only* upgraded Ubuntu.  It worked flawlessly until I did *this.*

(Yes, the user is a member of the appropriate Linux group. It *does* have permission.)

It's also interesting that `/dev/cdrom` is also not being mounted ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the summary of the final solution to this problem, based on my original answer below:

Referring to:
[Virtualbox - folder does not automatically mount, Windows 7 host Ubuntu 17.10 guest](https://superuser.com/questions/1295025/virtualbox-folder-does-not-automatically-mount-windows-7-host-ubuntu-17-10-gu/1349958#1349958)

I found that, contrary to the above page, `virtualbox-guest-utils.service` did *not* attempt to mount the shares.  The `vboxadd-service.service` does.  But you don't have that if you simply install the drivers extension-pack from virtualbox.org.  You need to install the extensions from the supplied CD-ROM, which on OS/X is part of the application package.

Then, the `Conflicts=` instruction was exactly correct:

```
sudo systemctl edit --full vboxadd-service
```

... then remove `systemd-timesync.service` from the `Conflicts=` list.  *(Go ahead and do this after you've installed from the CDRom and before you reboot.)*

Upon restart, your shares will be there.

Additional supporting information will be found in my original answer, below.

Answer (score 0):

I am revising my answer to be a much better one.

The overall situation I'm experiencing is best described here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066056/vbox-16-04-guest-upgraded-to-18-04-shared-folders-are-wrong

(Although *it* didn't receive "an answer," it *does* link to other pages that do, and I've cited some of those pages here.)

The problem appears to be in the `vboxadd-service`and/or the `vboxadd-guest-utils-service` as discussed in this "askubuntu" page:

[Virtualbox - folder does not automatically mount, Windows 7 host Ubuntu 17.10 guest](https://superuser.com/questions/1295025/virtualbox-folder-does-not-automatically-mount-windows-7-host-ubuntu-17-10-gu/1349958#1349958)

... which refers to this Ubuntu bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate/+bug/1769453

At this writing, I'm trying to ferret out exactly why the service is failing at startup in my case, but I *do* observe that the service is not running, and that if on my system I execute the following command, the shares appear:

```
sudo systemctl restart vboxadd-service.service
```

Unlike the cited post, however, my status for the service shows several services, some "exited":

```
● vboxadd.service
   Loaded: loaded (/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.2.18/init/vboxadd; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-08-23 12:06:20 EDT; 5min ago
  Process: 905 ExecStart=/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.2.18/init/vboxadd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 905 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 23 12:06:00 MyVM systemd[1]: Starting vboxadd.service...
Aug 23 12:06:03 myVM vboxadd[905]: VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
Aug 23 12:06:20 MyVM systemd[1]: Started vboxadd.service.

● vboxadd-service.service
   Loaded: loaded (/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.2.18/init/vboxadd-service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-08-23 12:11:20 EDT; 3s ago
  Process: 2696 ExecStart=/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.2.18/init/vboxadd-service start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 8 (limit: 4665)
   CGroup: /system.slice/vboxadd-service.service
           └─2737 /usr/sbin/VBoxService --pidfile /var/run/vboxadd-service.sh

Aug 23 12:11:19 MyVM systemd[1]: Starting vboxadd-service.service...
Aug 23 12:11:20 MyVM vboxadd-service[2696]: vboxadd-service.sh: Starting VirtualBox Guest Addition service.
Aug 23 12:11:20 MyVM vboxadd-service.sh[2717]: Starting VirtualBox Guest Addition service.
Aug 23 12:11:20 MyVM vboxadd-service.sh[2736]: VirtualBox Guest Addition service started.
Aug 23 12:11:20 MyVM systemd[1]: Started vboxadd-service.service.

● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-08-23 12:06:08 EDT; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1356 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 23 12:06:06 MyVM systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Aug 23 12:06:08 MyVM systemd[1]: Started LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
```

---

Undoubtedly, this "confusion" has considerable bearing on my problem . . .